# How to get a congruent euro symbol with erewhon font?

Tags: fonts, eurosym

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{erewhon}
\usepackage[]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

Hello!

\euro 100

\pounds 95

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the screnshot below, I get both symbols. But while the pound looks nice, the euro symbol seems to belong to a totally different font type. Can I get an `erewhon`-alike `\euro` symbol?

Comment: With `eurosym` you get the official Euro symbol, which is the only recognlzed symbol. Other realizations of the glyph may be tolerated, but usually they're even uglier than the official one.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have used \texteuro because the document is a CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `erewhon` package has a glyph for `\texteuro`, provided by the `textcomp` package (which is loaded by `erewhon`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{erewhon}

\begin{document}

Hello!

\texteuro 100

\pounds 95

\end{document}
```

[image]